# match duplicate string before a specified delimiter

Tags: awk, uniq

cat test.txt

```
serverabc.test.net
serverabc.qa.net
serverabc01.test.net
serverstag.staging.net
serverstag.test.net
```

here i need to match the duplicate strings just before the delimiter '.'
So the expected output would be like below. because string "serverabc" and "serverstag" found to be duplicates. Please help.

```
serverabc.test.net
serverabc.qa.net
serverstag.staging.net
serverstag.test.net
```

Comment: a) is the file already sorted?  If not, would it be OK to sort it?  b) In case of duplicates, is it OK to always take the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F\. '{c[$1]++; a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1]RS$0:$0}
         END{for(k in c) if(c[k]>1) print a[k]}' file

serverabc.test.net
serverabc.qa.net
serverstag.staging.net
serverstag.test.net
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not going to be used allot I would probably just do something like this:

```
cut -f1 -d\. foo.txt | sort |uniq -c | grep -v "      1 " | cut -c 9-|sed 's/\(.*\)/^\1\\./' > dup.host
grep -f dup.host foo.txt 
serverabc.test.net
serverabc.qa.net
serverstag.staging.net
serverstag.test.net
```